# Problem pushing image do ECR repository with aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I'm having a problem when I try to push the image to ecr, I'm trying to authenticate to the ecr repository before but it always appears this error:

Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://<MY_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request

I'm using the security credentials on the aws credentials file that were updated with aws configure command, what am I missing? Could someone help?

I'm using this command to authenticate do aws ecr repository(it is the same that I get from the ecr repository):
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <MY_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Yes, us-east-1 is the region where the repository was created and on the <MY_ACCOUNT_ID> I'm passing my own account id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
aws ecr get-login-password --profile <profile_name> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <ECR URI>
```

put in your profile and the ECR uri for the repository you are authenticating to.

Comment: if you go into the console you can copy the URI for the repositories. You can also use the cli for this `aws ecr describe-repositories`

Comment: Still the same problem :/

Comment: should work. do you have permissions to do this? I would try accessing your repo with AWS cli and see if that works.

Comment: You also could try specifying the region `--region us-east-1` in the first half, but this should be taken care of with the profile.

Comment: when I try the aws ecr describe-repositories, it works, the repo appears in the terminal, but with the get-login-password still the same problem, I've tried with --region us-east-1 also